# Share template site.master aspx(c#) with razor(cshtml)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have upgraded my project to mvc3 and want to keep all my pages and add new into it.
Now my question is if i start using razor, how can share my site.master template page between view.aspx(C#) and razor views(cshtml).
This is because i do not want to have my master page and its code duplicated for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Hanselman [blogged about this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx):

> Most commonly the scenario is that someone has an existing WebForms
>   (ASPX) Master Page that works nicely, and they now want to include a
>   few Razor pages in their application but don't want to maintain two
>   effectively identical Master Pages (one for ASPX, one for Razor). They
>   want to share their WebForms Master with both WebForms and Razor
>   Views.

And he provides the solution in his blog post.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use Master pages (*.master) with razor views (*.cshtml).
They are not compatible, razor views require a layout page to achieve what master pages offer.

You could create a layout page that has the same markup with the current master page. This will not really be duplication since they are not compatible.

Or better still you could just convert everything to razor, there are tools available to help automate the process. Check out this free tool by telerik [razor converter](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter)

Comment: Would have been nice to know the reason for the downvote ... might have learnt something new and would have fixed whatever wrong info i may have provided above in my answer.